# Cleaning HTML content of mail before sending : Python

Tags: html, python-2.7

I am sending an email with only HTML content using python library. The issue I am facing is the table present in HTML content few times gets distorted, and the row contents seems unaligned at times in mails sent.

Is there any programmatic way to ensure before sending mail that the HTML content will not distort. ?

Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: `Is there any programmatic way to ensure before sending mail that the HTML content will not distort. ?` unless you manually see the structure from your own eyes you cannot ensure its right. Only thing would be to make sure what is causing the issue and fix it...

Comment: Yeah, there are no programmatic ways for doing best appearance. There are a lot of logics and algorithms for doing consistent data and good appearance. So try to find logic of "distorted" and then you can fix it.

Comment: @Reddy ya i am checking the structure before sending it seems correct. actually the issue occurs when there is empty value for a column in a row.

Comment: @Bruce_Wayne So now you found out the bug, what else might fix the column? may be replacing empty value with `"       "` couple of spaces might help?

Comment: @Reddy ya good suggestion but i tried that already before posting.

Comment: how about a tab character `&#9;` in place of empty values?